# Android Spinner different arrow color

Tags: android, android-spinner

1) I have strange behavior with `Spinner`. If i add it to `Action Bar` with `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> barAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(mContext, R.layout.projects_filter_item, android.R.id.text1, mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.projects_filteres));
            barAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(barAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Then it is dark like this:
[image]

2) But if i add it in `onCreateOptionsMenu` with `ActionView` this arrow is white. I don't change any bg or color attributes.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_context_menu, menu);
    android.view.MenuItem filter = menu.findItem(R.id.context_menu_filter);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.projects_filter_item, 
            android.R.id.text1, getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.projects_filteres));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mFilterSpinner = (Spinner)MenuItemCompat.getActionView( filter);
    mFilterSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    mFilterSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long pos) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```

3) If I add Spinner somewhere in fragment it looks fine (is dark).

Why `Spinner` has this different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing theme doesn't help. If I add `Spinner` programmatically like this:

```
android.view.MenuItem filter = menu.findItem(R.id.context_menu_filter);
mFilterSpinner = new Spinner(getActionBar().getThemedContext()); // doesn't matter what context is here, Activity, Application or ActionBar
filter.setActionView(mFilterSpinner);
```

arrow of the `Spinner` is white.

But as i said, if i add Spinner in xml it looks fine.

So, i just create menu item as LinearLayout

```
<item
    android:title="Filter"
    android:visible="false"
    android:id="@+id/context_menu_filter"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.LinearLayout"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

And create simple xml with `Spinner`:

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in `onCreateOptionsMenu` manual inflate this layout and add to LinearLayout:

```
        android.view.MenuItem filter = menu.findItem(R.id.context_menu_filter);
        mFilterSpinner = (Spinner) ((LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.temp_spinner, null);
        filter.setVisible(true);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.projects_filter_item, 
                android.R.id.text1, getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.projects_filteres));
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView( filter);
        l.addView(mFilterSpinner);
        mFilterSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now it's dark like it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The theme should be something like:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="SomeParentStyle>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionBarSpinnerStyle</item><!-- if you use ABS -->
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyActionBarSpinnerStyle</item>
</style>
```

And `MyActionBarSpinnerStyle` should be something like:

```
<style name="MyActionBarSpinnerStyle" parent="@style/MyDropDownActionBarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_custom_state_list_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Where instead of `MyDropDownActionBarStyle` there should be something like `Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar` if you use ABS or `Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar` if you target only native ActionBar.

Comment: I don't want custom background for Spinner. I asked why it has different color in this 2 realizations?